# React js Semantic Menu items on center

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Hello I am having trouble leaving my content at the center of this div

code :
 https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-https-c5432

I tried to put the inline display on h5 and it still didn't work

```
<div className="App">
  <Menu
    className="borderless"
    style={{ width: "240px", height: "100vh" }}
    vertical
  >
    <Menu.Item className="logo">
      <Image src={logo} style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }} />
      <h5>E M A S A</h5>
      <Divider style={{ color: "#000 !important" }} />
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
</div>
```

css:

```
.ui.menu {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: #252631 !important;
}
.ui.menu .item {
  padding: 8px !important;
}
r {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}r {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make h5 tag or navigation links with center alignment? if yes then please check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-einstein-yl7p4

Comment: yes h5 and image on center and same row

Comment: please see i have updated the link, hope it is helpful to you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-einstein-yl7p4

Comment: I had looked, thanks but that's not it I need to put all menu items in the center in the same row

Comment: okay let me update the code and make all the item in center align

Comment: please see this updated link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-einstein-yl7p4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205424/discussion-between-ankitkanojia-and-mykon-spt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update **CSS**, Here is the [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-einstein-yl7p4)

> **JSX Code**

```
 <Menu
    className="borderless"
    style={{ width: "240px", height: "100vh" }}
    vertical>
    <Menu.Item className="logo">
      <h5>
        <Image
          src={logo}
          style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px", marginRight: "10px" }}
        />
        <span>E M A S A</span>
      </h5>
      <Divider style={{ color: "#000 !important" }} />
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
```

> **CSS**

```
.ui.menu {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: #252631 !important;
}

.ui.menu .item {
  padding: 8px !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui.menu .item h5 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ui.divider {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

img.ui.image {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: is this but i need image + h5 on same row

Comment: @MykonSpt please this update link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-einstein-yl7p4

Comment: Let me know in case of required anything

Comment: can you helpme one thing about display brother?

Comment: Yeah sure.. please do let me know.. I will help you within few hours. You can tell me

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bhaskara-tno10 about this sandbox i have a menu on the left and i wanted to put the two grids next to the menu

but for some reason I can't get it just below the menu

Comment: @MykonSpt do you want the grid in rightside section or below of menu section?

Comment: @MykonSpt, Hope this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-lederberg-d1jen helps to you. let me know in case of required anything

Comment: thanks bro is this / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621362/semantic-react-height-100-page if u want i can give vote up for this.

Comment: thanks bro, If it's not a problem could you help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638323/toggle-button-decrease-width-grid-and-div-semantic-react

Answer (score 2):

In order to align the **img** to center you can add
     `margin: 0 auto;`
      `display: block;`

and for aligning the text **h5** you can add
     `text-align: center;`

Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-glitter-9toif?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

i understood you need them on the same line so add this to the css `.ui.vertical.menu .item{display:flex;
justify-content:center;}`